# Count how many times a single letter appears in a word

Tags: javascript, string, charat

I am very new to JavaScript, and I'm trying to figure out how to count how many times a single letter appears in a word. For example, how many times does `'p'` appear in `'apple'`

Here is what I have written so far but am having trouble figuring out where am I going wrong.

```
var letterInWord = function (letter, word) {
  var letter = 0;
  var word = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < letter.charAt; i+= 1) {
    if (letter.charAt(i) === " " = true) {
        letter++;
        console.log('The letter `letter` occurs in `word` 1 time.');
    } 
  }
  return letter;
};
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You've got a number of problems:

1. You're reusing parameter names as local variable names. Use different identifiers to track each bit of information in your function.
2. `letter.charAt` is undefined, if `letter` is a number, and is a function if `letter` is a string. Either way, `i < letter.charAt` makes no sense.
3. If you're searching for `letter` in `word` why do you want to look at `letter.charAt(i)`? You probably want `word.charAt(i)`.
4. `" " = true` makes no sense at all.

Perhaps you meant something like this?

```
var letterInWord = function (letter, word) {
  var count = 0;
  for (var i = 0; i < word.length; i++) {
    if (word.charAt(i) === letter) {
        count++;
    } 
  }
  return count;
};
```

Comment: Thank you, im confused ya cause im new :) question. I copied your code into Chrome console, but must not be running it right, cause I always get back errors. what function should I be running to see the console.log output I was going for?

Comment: @jstone What error are you seeing? It runs fine on my console.

Comment: I type `var letterInWord = function (letter, word) { ... };` and hit enter; the result is `undefined` (because of the `var`). I then type `letterInWord('p', 'apple')` and hit enter, the result is 2.

Comment: Thanks ur awesome. There is one last part im stuck on: I am trying to print this out in the console. console.log('The letter 'letter' occurs in 'word' 'X' times.'). I am getting this syntax error, so someway I am writing it doesn't seem to be working right.

Comment: @jstone that's because you're using single quotes to delimit your string as well as single quotes inside your string. The easiest solution is just to use double quotes to delimit the string: `console.log("The letter 'letter' occurs in 'word' 'X' times.")`

Comment: I did get that part working, although a few issues, I can get that to print to the console, although 'letter' never shows as 'a' and 'word' never shows 'apple'. Lastly I cant figure out how to solve for 'X'

Comment: You'll have to construct the string yourself, e.g. `console.log("The letter '" + letter + "' occurs in '" + word + "' '" + count + "' times.")`

Answer (score 1):

```
'apple'.match(/p/g).length // outputs 2
```

in other words:

```
var letterInWord = function (letter, word) {
  return (word.match( new RegExp(letter, 'g') ) || []).length;
};
```

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/82xDz/1/)

Comment: Thanks, although im confused what you just did as in where you put that in my code to get that to work, or was that something you put in the console to run?

Comment: It just seemed a lot easier to do it this way ?

Comment: @jstone - the one-line function shown in this answer completely replaces your existing nine-line function. It's an alternative method of calculating the letter count.

Comment: Just a caution: this will not work for some characters, e.g. `$` will always return 1, `.` will always return the length `word`.

Comment: @p.s.w.g - well, those aren't really characters in a word !

Comment: And if it really was an issue, here's the solution -> http://jsfiddle.net/82xDz/3/

Comment: @adeneo I'm not saying it's a bad solution--in fact it's probably pretty close to what I would write in my own code--just that OP should use caution with this as it can lead to some unexpected results and would be really confusing for someone that didn't have a reasonable grasp on how regular expressions work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a smaller function that also works with characters like `$` or `*` (and since it's calling `length` on a string, there's no need to use `|| []`)

```
'apple'.replace(/[^p]/g,'').length // outputs 2



function charcount(c, str) {
  return str.replace(new RegExp('[^'+c+']','g'),'').length
}

console.log = function(x) { document.write(x + "<br />"); };
console.log( "'*' in '4*5*6' = " + charcount('*', '4*5*6') ) // outputs 2
console.log( "'p' in 'pineapples' = " + charcount('p', 'pineapples') )// outputs 3
```